# Dynamic type casting in swift 4

Tags: swift, casting

I've got a class named `Filters`

```
class Filters {

   typealias States = [State]
   typealias Cities = [City]
   typealias Areas = [Area]

   var states : States?
   var cities : Cities?
   var areas : Areas?
}
```

In a `FilterViewController`, based on user's selection, `pickerViewItems` will be populated with items of `filters.states`, `filters.cities` or `filters.areas`.

The problem is when I populate the `pickerViewItems` with one of the three array item, e.g. `filters.states`, I can't cast it to `States` so I will be able to use

`pickerViewItems[row].name`

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'name'

How can I set the type of `pickerViewItems` dynamically in Swift?

Comment: Use protocol which confirms to state, city and area . keep a property "name" in protocol  which will be  get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift is pretty much a static language so you can't dynamically change the type. Therefore, we are going to use *polymorphism* to work around this.

Assuming that `State`, `City` and `Area` all have a `name` property, you can create an protocol like this:

```
protocol NamedLocation {
    var name: String { get; }
}
```

And make all three classes conform to the protocol:

```
extension State: NamedLocation { }
extension City: NamedLocation { }
extension Area: NamedLocation { }
```

Now you can make your `pickerViewItems` to be of type `[NamedLocation]` and you can still access the `name` property.